# Extended Feynman-Kac

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

I have mostly only seen application of Feynman-Kac where the RHS is 0, but I have recently stumpled upon a case where a deterministic function is included, and so the boundary problem is as  stated:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}+\mu(t,x)\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t,x)\frac{\partial^
2 F}{\partial x^2}-r(t,x)F+k(t,x)&=0\\
F(T,x)&=\Phi(x)
\end{align*}

How would a solution for $F$ look like? (Note: I have answered my own question, but would like criticism of any mistake or errors I might have made)

Answer (score 1):

The answer, as mentioned by @podiki, can be found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula)

Answer (score 0):

My take on this was to seperate the problem into something known, so here goes.
*Proof*: Firstly we split up the problem into two boundary problems with the first being $F$ dependant and the other $K$ dependant. Firstly, consider the function
$$G(t,x)=E_{t,x}\left[\mathrm e^{-\int_t^Tr(u,x_u)du}\Phi(x)\right]$$
Hence we have
\begin{align*}
      \frac{\partial G}{\partial t}+\mu(t,x)\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t,x)\frac{\partial^
2 G}{\partial x^2}-r(t,x)G&=0\\
G(T,x)&=\Phi(x)
\end{align*}
Secondly, consider the function
$$H(t,x)=\int_t^T E_{t,x}\left[\mathrm e^{-\int_t^s r(u,x_u)du}k(s,x_s)\right]ds$$
Which again must staisfy the PDE
\begin{align*}
      \frac{\partial H}{\partial t}+\mu(t,x)\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(t,x)\frac{\partial^
2 H}{\partial x^2}-r(t,x)H&=k(t,x)\\
H(T,x)&=0
\end{align*}
Lastly impose that $F(t,x)=G(t,x)+H(t,x)$ in which by linearity of derivatives the yields exatly the original boundary problem. Which would then yield:
$$F(t,x)=E_{t,x}\left[\mathrm e^{-\int_t^Tr(u,x_u)du}\Phi(x)\right]+\int_t^TE_{t,x}\left[\mathrm e^{-\int_t^sr(u,x_u)du}k(t,s)\right]ds$$

Comment: I think you are missing a $\Phi$ in your original formula for $G(t,x)$ as well as some subscripts on the expectation in the final formula for $F(t,x)$. Also I think you ca write your final answer as a single expectation by Fubini.

Comment: Yes, I'm missing the boundary condition in $G$ and subscripts. I think it is nice/neat to keep the expectation in the last term seperate in the last case since we can have case of the boundary being 0, but I will take a look on simplifying it :)

Comment: Now edited with your comments @podiki

Comment: This is more or less the way the FK formula is stated and proved on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula)

Comment: Yes, I see that now... Thanks for the assist @podiki